# emoticon, textarea with raw and textfield with replaced icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, emoticons

I have an editable div and there it should replace emoticon-keys while typing.
There is an hidden textarea also and there should be the raw data, but i dont't get how this should work.
I use this [library](http://benalman.com/code/projects/javascript-emotify/examples/adium-emoticonset/).
My jquery code:

```
         $('#acompose_message').keyup(function() {
                val = $('#acompose_message').html();
                document.getElementById('compose_message').innerHTML = val;
                emotifyVal = emotify(val);
                $('#acompose_message').html(emotifyVal);

        });
```

'#acompose_message' is the editable div and '#compose_message' is the hidden div

Comment: what exactly do you build? Chat system ? Or a forum ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I almost solved my problem :

```
var emotifyText = function(e) {
            var caretPosition = getCaretPosition(this);
            var images = [];
            var i = 0;
            val = $('#acompose_message').html();
            var emotifyVal = emotify(val);
            $('#acompose_message').html(emotifyVal);
            $.each($('#acompose_message img'), function(index){
                console.log(i);
                $(this).replaceWith(function(){
                    return jQuery.inArray( $(this).attr('src'), jsonIcons );
                });
                i++;
            });

            val = $('#acompose_message').html();
            var emotifyVal = emotify(val);
            $('#compose_message').val(val);
            $('#acompose_message').html(emotify(val));
    };
```

but the line with `$(this).replaceWith(function(){` does not work, now my Question is, does somebody knows how i can replace every img in my div with an other string?

Comment: Ok now i solved it it was the jsonIcons array, because in there the img informations are stored in this way : [':)' => ['path/to/img', 'name', 'alternative_key']] `$.each($('#acompose_message img'), function(index){
                    var src = $(this).attr('src');
                    for (var key in jsonIcons) {
                            if(jQuery.inArray(src , jsonIcons[key] ) != -1) {
                                $(this).replaceWith(key);
                            }
                    }
                    i++;
                });`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are new to js.  But this isn't our problem.  You want to build a chatsystem with emoticons. Not a problem either. You jsut need to reconsider your approach.

1. Insteed of using image emoticons in that phase, use ready-html emoticons. Take a look here [Emoticons HTMl](http://character-code.com/emoticons-html-codes.php). They are ready emoticons that can be configure like a text. You can copy-paste and do all the other staff you do with letters. If you see every emoticon have a value (eg & #128512;)  (Give a try now..copy and paste a emoticon. Oh here is one..😀 ) You can also specify color, font-size, etc values in css just like it was LETTERS (did i mention that ? ;)
2. Now for the scripting part. With Ready-Html emoticons you need to reconsider your approach for JavaScript. Why don't you made first a select box to select your emoticons rather than convert text? Take a look in Google-Hangout and Facebook or Skype. They have a face-button which show you the faces. From that point all you need to do is click on the image you like (in your case Ready_Html emoticon) and will be placed in your text input. Then you can handle an `on-enter` event to send the message to the other client.

To sum up.
Use Ready HTML emoticons like this:

```
<div style="color: red; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif;">&#128512; </div>
```

The user can select an emoticon from a pop up button: here is an image example:

And here is a typical js code:

For the emoticon-button:

```
$('#emonicons').click(function() {
        if (emojis_isShown) {
            $('.spawn-emonicons').fadeOut(300);
            emojis_isShown = false;
        }
        else {
            $('.spawn-emonicons').fadeIn(300);
            emojis_isShown = true;
        }

});
```

For the actual icons:

```
$('.ico').click(function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        var input = $('#message-sender');
        input.val(input.val() + value + ' ');

});
```

In the second code, when user press the icon he wants, the icons is transfered to input text with id `message-sender`.
Now to handle on key press enter , which will send your message you can use the following pseudo function in JS.

```
 $('#message-sender').bind('keydown', function (event) {
         if(event.which === 13) {
            emojis_isShown = false;
            $('.spawn-emonicons').hide();
            var msg = $(this).val();
            var newdiv1 = '<div class="whatever">'+msg+'</div>'

               $( newdiv1 ).insertAfter( $( ".message" ).last());

         }
 });
```

The code above read all the keypresses and when key 13 (which is enter) is pressed then hide the emoticons window. create a new div with the message you typed and send it to front end. 
You should also consider to use Ajax to send the message to the 'other side' (Ops I mean client).

I'm deeply sorry if I couldn't help you more. The chatbox system is a taught task and not recommended to new programmers (Who said that???)

The last think I can give you is a tutorial I found on `dreamincode.com` about building a simple chat box. Start with that. With the time and as you become better programmer you will find the solutions you seek!

Tutorial (A really nice one) :  [Simple Text Chat Box](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44808-simple-text-chat-box/)

Comment: @Juli55 hmmm why is that?

Comment: my client wants to add pictures to an folder and then he want to use this pics as emoticons

Comment: @Juli55 As a full-stack developer you should consider alternatives. To to your client about my alternative. And if my answer satisfied you at least in some point, please accept it.

Comment: Ok, he won't that, because he want to use the images from an folder